# Finding the mean using RxJava

Tags: java, statistics, rx-java

I'm learning RxJava and this is what I attempted to find the mean of 'n' transactions.

```
List<Transaction> transactions = TransactionsStore.getTransactions();
BigDecimal nTransactions = new BigDecimal(transactions.size());
Observable.from(transactions)
        .map(transaction -> transaction.amount)
        .reduce(BigDecimal::add)
        .map(total -> total.divide(nTransactions, 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN))
        .map(mean -> String.format("The mean is %s", mean.toPlainString()))
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

I'd like to know if this could be done better.

Answer (score -1):

Using RxJava-Math you can achieve the same result by this way:

```
List<Transaction> transactions = createRandomTransactions(10);

final Observable<Float> amountStream = Observable.from(transactions)
        .map(transaction -> transaction.amount);

MathObservable.averageFloat(amountStream)
        .map(mean -> String.format(Locale.US, "The mean is %.2f", mean))
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Please try to explain how this is an improvement of the existing code

Comment: Am I not losing precision here by using `Float`? My code sample uses `BigDecimal`, in case you didn't notice.

Comment: I'm just showing a different way to achieve the mean. I noticed that you are using BigDecimal, but you don't explicit defined this as a strong requirement in your question.